# How do I get my Dashboard to advise anything but 'Sorry, there is nothing that matches your search'?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

The statement `Sorry, there is nothing that matches your search` comes as a result (virtually invariably) upon my entering just about anything in the command line or search string in Dashboard.

This is a problem, because it prevents me doing much of anything - including anything `sudo`.. (for example `sudo ufw status` or `sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades`. Seems therefore to be an important wall I just can't seem to get through, over, under, or around. I'm extremely new to Ubuntu (ver. 12.04.4), but have been using PCs for about 28 years, so I'm familiar with DOS and comfortable issuing commands in that manner - but I can't seem to get in the front door or to get the Dashboard's attention.

- I tried `unity --replace &`, installed `unity-place-applications` and also `unity-place-files` as well to no avail.

Is there an easier, more direct way to sort this out (or do I just need to re-install the software)?

Comment: You need to open a terminal to run terminal commands, not search for them in unity.

Comment: Got it. Rookie error, I reckon. Thanks to everyone for your help - you guys rock!

Comment: @belacqua none can be marked, since was OP misunderstanding of how dash worked

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I can understand the question correctly but if you want to run command line tools from the dash then press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> instead of pressing the <kbd>super</kbd> key (windows key) but you should replace things like sudo with gksudo since it will not open in the terminal

a better solution would be to write terminal commands in the terminal itself 
just <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal then use the commands you need

Comment: Thank you. Yep.. the question wasn't entirely clear, but I think you nailed it despite my best efforts at clarity. I Just have to begin to shake some of the DOS/Windows mentality that is so ingrained, and start thinking Linux. Only been at this a few days. I know it gets better...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds so to me like you are trying to use the Dash as the terminal. The search box in Dash will find files, programs etc on your computer. For example, to open Rhythmbox you would hit `Super` to open the Dash and then start typing in "Rhythmbox". As you type, you should get a live update that matches the letters you are typing. When you see the Rhythmbox icon pop up in results then would click on that icon to open the program. To run a command like `sudo apt-get install` you would need to open the Terminal by typing "Terminal" into the dash and clicking on it (or using the `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T` to open the terminal) and then entering your sudo commands there. If the terminal doesn't open, or typing file name or program names into Dash still don't list results, then you have bigger problems.

Comment: You're exactly right. Thanks for taking the time to clarify and to explain (esp. Dash v. Terminal) so clearly. It's kind of like learning a new language in 3 days - I need to get more patient and would probably stumble onto things like the Ctrl + Alt + T in time.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark one of these as an answer.